# IPython notebook markdown -- what are the list of allowed HTML tags and how can I change them?

Tags: html, svg, jupyter-notebook

I'm using IPython Notebook markdown to create a document and it does allow some HTML like `<img>` for example but I added `<object>` to include an SVG file and it does not show up in the IPython Notebook output. I double-checked the HTML source of the IPython Notebook and the `<object>` tag is not served by the IPython Notebook server. Looks like the `<iframe>` tag is sanitized also.

Whereas when I convert it myself outside of IPython Notebook to an HTML file, it works fine. Is there something I need to do to add `<object>` and `<iframe>` to the list of allowed HTML tags?

---

I found Jupyter's [security.js](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/666ecbf35c3310335a3c8c182e8f53441c991c14/notebook/static/base/js/security.js#L79) but not sure whether this runs on the server or the client, and not sure how to alter it.

I also tried File → Trust Notebook but that didn't fix it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I monkeypatched my local copy of site-packages/notebook/static/notebook/js/main.min.js to have this:

```
var sanitize_html = function (html, allow_css) {
    /**
     * sanitize HTML
     * if allow_css is true (default: false), CSS is sanitized as well.
     * otherwise, CSS elements and attributes are simply removed.
     */
    var html4 = caja.html4;

    if (allow_css) {
        // allow sanitization of style tags,
        // not just scrubbing
        html4.ELEMENTS.style &= ~html4.eflags.UNSAFE;
        html4.ATTRIBS.style = html4.atype.STYLE;
    } else {
        // scrub all CSS
        html4.ELEMENTS.style |= html4.eflags.UNSAFE;
        html4.ATTRIBS.style = html4.atype.SCRIPT;
    }

    /* BEGIN NEW CODE */
    var whitelist_key = html.match(/<span class="whitelist:([0-9A-Za-z-_]+)"\s+\/?>/)
    if (whitelist_key && whitelist_key[1]== /* password goes here */)
    {
        console.log("whitelist ok");
        html4.ELEMENTS.object &= ~html4.eflags.UNSAFE;
        html4.ATTRIBS['iframe::src'] = 0; 
        html4.ATTRIBS['object::data'] = 0; 
        html4.ATTRIBS['object::type'] = 0; 
    }
    /* END NEW CODE */
```

and then in the cells of my notebook I add `<span class="whitelist:mypassword" />`

It works for now, I've opened [issue #2614](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2614) on github.